# Combining two Joint Probabablity Disributions Into One

Tags: probability

Given the graph $A$->$B$->$C$, $A$ is independent of $C$ given $B$. I have the joint probability distribution of $A$ and $B$ as $P(A,B)$ and the joint probability distribution of $B$ and $C$ as $P(B, C)$. How to compute the joint probability distribution $P(A,B,C)$ ?

Moreover, I want to know how to compute the conditional probability distribution $P(B|C)$ as $\sum_A P(B|C,A)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

From the graph, $A$ and $C$ are conditionally independent given $B$:

$$P(C,A|B)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B)}=P(A|B)P(C|B)=\frac{P(A,B)P(C,B)}{P(B)^2}$$

Comment: there is this case in the problem I am trying to solve is that I only can compute  B only by summing over A  that's why I am trying with the second part

Comment: @Moh, Likewise you can only compute $\mathsf P(C)$ by summing the over $B$. $\mathsf P(C)=\mathsf P(B,C)+\mathsf P(B^{\small\complement}, C)$

Answer (score 0):

> I have the joint probability distribution of $A$ and $B$ as $\mathsf P(A,B)$ and the joint probability distribution of $B$ and $C$ as $\mathsf P(B,C)$.  How to compute the joint probability distribution $\mathsf P(A,B,C)$?

You shall need $\mathsf P(B)$, which you can obtain if you also have $\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement}, B)$ or $\mathsf P(B, C^{\small\complement})$ .

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A,B,C) &=\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(C\mid B)&&\text{according to the DAG: }A\to B\to C\\[1ex]&= \mathsf P(A,B)\,\mathsf P(C\mid B)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,B)\,\mathsf P(B,C)}{\mathsf P(B)} \\[1ex]&= \dfrac{\mathsf P(A,B)\,\mathsf P(B,C)}{\mathsf P(A,B)+\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement},B)}&&= \dfrac{\mathsf P(A,B)\,\mathsf P(B,C)}{\mathsf P(B,C)+\mathsf P(B, C^{\small\complement})}\end{align}$$

> Moreover, I want to know how to compute the conditional probability distribution P(B|C)

Similarly, you will also need $\mathsf P(B^{\small\complement},C)$, or a means to obtain it.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B\mid C) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B, C)}{\mathsf P(C)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B,C)}{\mathsf P(B,C)+\mathsf P(B^{\small\complement}, C)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for your respond is there a way to compute P(B|C) by summing over A ? Like $\sum_A P(B|CA)$ ?

Comment: @Moh Well...$$\mathsf P(B\mid C)=\sum_\mathcal A \mathsf P(\mathcal A,B\mid C)$$